# Shih Tzu with food aggression behavior problems

Tags: dogs, behavior, diet, aggression

I have a male Shih Tzu dog that is just over a year old (not neutered), and he has food aggression behavioral problems. We got him when he was just a month old, and he tends to be a picky eater (maybe this is normal for this breed?).

He will sometimes bark at us when we're eating if he wants us to share our food, but it doesn't happen too often (I've been trying to train him to sit using food as a reward). The real issue though is that he gets **really** food aggressive if other dogs are around. The vet did say he was a little underweight last time we took him.

Sometimes he will even gobble down food he previously didn't want if he thinks there's a chance another dog might get it, and we've been having issues with him growling and getting in fights with other dogs over food.

What can I do to help this? Is there a way to curb this behavior?

Comment: At which occassion other dogs are around while feeding time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I cure food agression in my dog when preliminary techniques have failed?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-can-i-cure-food-agression-in-my-dog-when-preliminary-techniques-have-failed)

Comment: @Allerleirauh - I'm in the Philippines where there are a lot of strays and other dogs just roaming around so it happens if one comes to the house, or if my dog is around other dogs while food scraps are thrown in their direction.

Comment: @AllisonC - Sort of. It's not so a much a resource guarding of a bowl. It's more like he feels entitled to any food whenever there are other animals around.

Comment: To be honest, what you describe sounds very normal to me. Not every dog is protective of their food, but most dogs will quickly eat whatever is available before another dog steals it. My dog even thinks the vacuum cleaner will steal his food so he gobbles it all down whenever we vacuum the floor.